Is it possible to have several dynamically linked Go libs in one process?
The main question - is it possible to have several Go runtimes linked dynamically into one binary and running in the one process?
I have two Go libraries which are linked into one Swift app and after go1.21 the application started to fail because of these libraries on macOS x86_64 only (the arm or Windows is fine). The libraries are linked dynamically.
To modulate the situation, let's say I have:
Library #1
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef const char const_char_t;
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {}

//export GetFirstString
func GetFirstString() *C.const_char_t {
    fmt.Println("Call to golib1.GetFirstString()")
    return C.CString("Hello from golib1")
}


Library #2
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef const char const_char_t;
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {}

//export GetSecondString
func GetSecondString() *C.const_char_t {
    fmt.Println("Call to golib2.GetSecondString()")
    s := fmt.Sprintf(`{"data":%s}`, "golib2")

    return C.CString(s)
}

main.cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "build/libgolib1.h"
#include "build/libgolib2.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Starting the test app" << std::endl;

    const char* string1 = GetFirstString();
    std::cout << "First string: " << string1 << std::endl;
    free((void*)string1);

    const char* string2 = GetSecondString();
    std::cout << "Second string: " << string2 << std::endl;
    free((void*)string2);
}

Build commands
cd golib1 && go build -o ../build/libgolib1.so -buildmode=c-shared .
cd golib2 && \
    GOTRACEBACK=all \
    GOEXPERIMENT=cgocheck2 \
    go build -o ../build/libgolib2.so -buildmode=c-shared .
clang++ -std=c++20 -g -I. -L./build -o test_app main.cpp \
    -lgolib1 \
    -lgolib2 \
    -framework CoreFoundation \
    -framework Security

The output I see (does not happen everytime)
> DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=./build ./test_app
Starting the test app
Call to golib1.GetFirstString()
First string: Hello from golib1
write of unpinned Go pointer 0x1c00009a000 to non-Go memory 0xc000190050
fatal error: unpinned Go pointer stored into non-Go memory

runtime stack:
runtime.throw({0x10c370cee?, 0x7ff8123ee54e?})
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.22.3/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:1023 +0x5c fp=0x7ff7b469c460 sp=0x7ff7b469c430 pc=0x10c3091bc
runtime.cgoCheckPtrWrite.func1()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.22.3/libexec/src/runtime/cgocheck.go:68 +0x85 fp=0x7ff7b469c490 sp=0x7ff7b469c460 pc=0x10c2d9b05
runtime.systemstack(0xc000056008)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.22.3/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:509 +0x4a fp=0x7ff7b469c4a0 sp=0x7ff7b469c490 pc=0x10c338aca
...

Used:

go version go1.22.3 darwin/amd64
Homebrew clang version 18.1.6

Additional note
The usage of fmt is not required to have a failure.
The expected output is:
Starting the test app v2
Call to golib1.GetFirstString()
First string: Hello from golib1
Call to golib2.GetSecondString()
Second string: {"data":golib2}


Loading multiple go runtimes is not supported, and you may encounter problems. I've seen it kind of work with Linux (though I don't necessarily trust it to be stable), but with non-ELF executables you are in untested territory.

It's bad that I cannot find anything on this topic in the off. docs. Now I'm wondering if it's possible to remove one runtime by some hack. But ofc, because of the GC and stuff, most likely it is not possible
